# Aligning object to the X Axis

Tags: physics

I have a spaceship I have designed and want to import this in to Unreal Engine.   Unreal engine requires the ship to be pointing down the X Axis at the moment, mine is pointing down the Y axis.
How can I change the Axis so that the ship is pointing down the X Axis?

[image: Ship on wrong axis]

Comment: Have you tried setting the axis up / forward option in the fbx exporter (I'm assuming you're using fbx).  Blender is -Y forward and Z up.   Try exporting with X (or -X) as the forward axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>R</kbd> to rotate it and then type in the number of degrees want to rotate it (in this case either: 90, or -90). I would also press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to center your *3D Cursor* and then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and select: offset to 3D cursor, to center your object.

Comment: Great - thanks for that, I have one last question. When I use R it allows me to move the ship round but its not flat now ??

Comment: I have used R successfully and now need to make the ship be flat?
So I need to pull the left wing down to be flat.
I know this is very basic but I cant find the answer :( [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nfAP.png) Thanks

Comment: Git it - I needed to use the X key :-)